# Usage of the verb "squinch" in AmEng

Tags: american-english, word-usage, disambiguities, dialects

[Collins American English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/squinch) says:

> squinch (skwɪntʃ)
>
> (*US*)
>
> ***transitive verb***
>
> 1. to squint (the eyes); *squinched up her eyes in disgust.* [M-W](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/thesaurus?book=Thesaurus&va=squinch)
>
> > 2.
>
> a. to pucker or screw up (the face, nose, brow, etc.); *Jonathan squinched his face into a grimace.* [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22squinched+his+face+into%22&biw=599&bih=393&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIqpDxuonLAhXKuhQKHe_SBPEQ_AUICygG&dpr=2)
>
> b. to squeeze or compress; *She squinched the paper up in an angry twist and stood to throw it into the stove* [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KiUlbmAsp_EC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%22squinched+the+paper%22&source=bl&ots=vzIAaEuq2y&sig=_BIb48gSKJuGOz86nyu-ZIqa7OY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-iL_PvonLAhVHfxoKHbrBD7UQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22squinched%20the%20paper%22&f=false); *Robert squinched the ketchup bottle, trying to get the last bit out.*
>
> ***intransitive verb***
>
> 3. to squint, pucker, or contort
> 4. to crouch down or draw oneself together so as to seem smaller; [*I squinched down under the sheet*](http://nicedefinition.com/Definition/Word/squinch/squinch.aspx); [*The man squinched down to fit under the table*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squinch) (Source: [American Literature Unit 11 Vocab Notes](https://englishteacherjrt.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/american-literature-unit-11-vocab-notes.docx).)
> 5. to flinch
>
> Word Origin: probably blend of *squint* and *pinch*
>
> First Known Use: 1835
>
> Example Sentences Including "squinch:"
>
> *Cooper saw her **squinch up** her eyes, trying to make out who was standing outside her kitchen window*.
>
> *An unhappy smile is still a smile, insofar as the corners of the mouth are drawn back or upturned. However, the eyebrows may be furrowed, and the eyes may be **squinched** or teary. Also, the lips tend to be pressed together, rather than relaxed as in a happy smile.* [**ELU**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31064/an-unhappy-smile/31070#31070)

My question is, how do native speakers of AmEng use the verb ***squinch*** in the senses supported above by CAED?

In addition, what's the difference between using either "squinch" or "squint/flinch" as in the following examples:

> *She squinched (up) her eyes, trying to make out who was standing outside.*
>
> *She squinted her eyes, trying to make out who was standing outside.*

-and-

> *The driver squinched as the sun hit his windshield.*
>
> [*The driver squinted as the sun hit his windshield.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Squint)

-and-

> [*The children squinched so as to scare each other.*](http://www.spellinger.com/squinch)
>
> [*The children squinted so as to scare each other.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Squint)

-and-

> *He squinched as the cold water struck him.*
>
> [*He flinched as the cold water struck him.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flinch)

-and-

> [*She squinched when they showed the slaughtering of the calf.*](http://www.spellinger.com/squinch)
>
> [*She flinched when they showed the slaughtering of the calf.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flinch)

Comment: It's mostly just a more colorful, jocular way to say "squint".

Comment: *"The children squinched so as to scare each other"* doesn't seem idiomatic to me, as an intransitive verb. Do you mean *"squinched (up) their eyes"* or *"squinched (up) their faces"*?  And you wouldn't use *up* in *squinted up her eyes*. Aside from that, I think all your suggested usages are fine, and are more or less synonymous with the alternatives.

Comment: @PeterShor I mean "squinched their eyes," as defined in the 1st sense of "squinch" as an intransitive verb.

Comment: I think *squinch* is less suggestive of weakness than either *squint* or *flinch.*

Comment: @Elian: with so many different meanings of *squinch*, if you want to use it to mean *squinched their eyes*, you need context that rules out all the other meanings. Like *"she squinched to see the castle in the distance"*.

Comment: This is not a common word. It sounds like a made-up portmanteau, or a mistake.

Comment: @Mitch http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200063/word-for-getting-hit-in-the-head-lowering-your-neck-and-raising-your-shoulder/200064#200064 ;-)

Comment: @elian That's great. I wonder how often I've done that in the past and just didn't have a written record to show it.

Comment: Elian: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200063/word-for-getting-hit-in-the-head-lowering-your-neck-and-raising-your-shoulder/200064#comment423501_200064

Comment: An item titled "[Vulgarisms](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn98060050/1839-01-18/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22squinch%22)" in the _[Brattleboro] Vermont Phoenix_ (January 18, 1839), includes _squinch_ as the last entry  in a "list of unpardonable vulgarisms [first] published in a New Hampshire paper, half a century ago," which would mean circa  1789 (if the dubious claim is to be believed). Although _squinch_ is used as a verb in this list, its meaning is quite different from any of the ones listed the Collins Dictionary that you cite: "Squinch [misused] for Quench."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that **squint** describes the action of the facial muscles in a  neutral way, whereas **squinch up** is used in contexts where the speaker wants to characterize or emphasize how the person's face looks when they are squinting. The **up** draws attention to the appearance of the facial musculature.

Comment: See also scrunch http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scrunch which is identical in usage to what Tim describes.

Comment: @H.R.Rambler How would you use "squinch" in Sense 2b.? Would saying "Robert squinched the ketchup bottle, trying to get the last bit out" make any sense to you?

Comment: Yup, granted I wouldn't say squinched or scrunched personally... But that matches the synonym for 'squeeze', and if the ketchup bottle stayed in a squeezed state the the bottle might be 'squinched up' at that point.

Comment: @H.R.Rambler, how about intransitive "squinch" in Sense 3? What would be a nice example sentence for it?

Comment: @H.R.Rambler - Yeah, "scrunch" is much more familiar in the US, and has many of the same meanings.

Comment: heh, I'm an etymology nerd. I better leave syntax to those better qualified

Answer (score 1):

I use the transitive verb definition 2b.  A typical example is:
"Many fonts have the lower-case  r  horizontally squinched."
I would never use it to mean squint.
I am in Illinois, but have lived in several other states.

Comment: When you use "squinched" in this manner, do others generally know what you mean?